# OpenCV VideoCapture using H.264 Camera

Tags: c++, opencv, embedded-linux

I've got an embedded linux device with a USB Camera attached which provides an MJPEG as well as an H.264 stream. Until now, I used the MJPEG stream (device index 0) to initialize my VideoCapture object and to read frames from the camera. The problem is that the CPU of the device isn't exactly powerful, so decoding utilizes a lot of it, which is why I want to use the H.264 stream (device index 2) that the camera already provides. However, OpenCV refuses to accept this format at all.

```
Aug 23 08:08:17: VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
Aug 23 08:08:17: VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 2
```

After several online searches I found that you can hint OpenCV to accept H.264 streams by setting the FourCC value of the object `cap.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC, VideoWriter::fourcc('H', '2', '6', '4'));`, but this didn't do the trick.

I also tried "avc1", which didn't work as well.

Is there any way how I can use the native H.264 stream of the camera using OpenCV or am I stuck with MJPEG?

Comment: first of all are you sure `H264`  will be faster than `MJPEG` ? I believe absolutely no.

Comment: Does your build of opencv have a h264 codec built in?

Comment: other questions: 1- `-D WITH_V4L=ON` enabled build opencv ? 2- what makes you sure index 2 has h264 streaming, index 0 MJPEG. what about index 1

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk It doesn't have to be fast, it just has to have lower CPU utilization. And I know that it's index 2 because I've used the ```udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/elp-h264)``` command and it said that it is the video2 device.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't know, I'm using the OpenCV version that is included in the yocto-linux dunfell-branch as this is what the embedded system is working with.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/dc4/group__videoio__hwaccel.html -- see if you can request H.264, and make sure whatever hardware codec of your platform is used

Comment: I used the MJPEG stream (device index 0) to initialize my VideoCapture object and to read frames from the camera......VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 2